# how to inactivate a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, global-variables

I have a javascript function that I'd like to be able to turn off when it is no longer needed.   It is called "lockdown" and prevents students from navigating to other websites while taking a quiz.   If they do attempt to go elsewhere, they are sent to a different URL that says that they have violated the "lockdown" rules.

When the function "lockdown" is activated, a variable called "locked" is set to "1" and this causes the function to be active.

Now I sometimes want to stop the "lockdown" function so I made another function called "stoplockdown" that changes the "locked" variable to a different number.   It seems like this should stop the function from being executed because there is an "if" clause that relies on "locked" being "1".   So it seems that if "locked" is not "1", the rest of the events would not occur.

I am able to successfully call both "lockdown" and "stoplockdown" from another program but "stoplockdown" doesn't turn off the lockdown function.   Here is the javascript:

```
<!--lockdown and stop lockdown--->

<script>
<!--declare variable outside of function to give it a global scope--->
var locked=2;


function lockdown(){
locked=1;
alert(locked);
if(locked==1){
// next event prevents resizing or starting with small window to allow for split screen cheating in lockdown mode.
if (window.outerHeight<screen.availHeight || window.outerWidth<screen.availWidth) {
window.location.href = 
'https://quizninja.net/lockdown.html';
}
window.addEventListener("resize", resized);
function resized(){
window.location.href = 
'https://quizninja.net/lockdown.html';
}
// previous event prevents resizing or starting with small window window to allow for split screen cheating in lockdown mode.

// next event redirects to another page if quiz loses focus

  window.onblur = function (){
  window.location.href = 
'https://quizninja.net/lockdown.html';
}
}
}

 // to make it complete, also add onblur to document.
// For browsers using tabs (like firefox)
document.onblur = window.onblur;
document.focus = window.focus;

//stop lockdown
function stoplockdown(){
locked=0;
alert(locked);
}

</script>


<!-- javascript function to close window if not in focus for lockdown browser mode ENDS...-->
e
```

Why doesn't this work?   I am a bit new to javascript and am not an expert programmer in general.   It seems that "locked" should have a global scope but it doesn't seem to alter to stop the "if" clause of the "lockdown" function when you change its value.   Any suggestions would be appreciated.   Thanks.

Comment: Whats to stop students disabling your lockdown using the console?

Comment: `functionName = undefined`.

Comment: `lockdown` does set `locked=1;` its first line.

Comment: This is also easily bypassed by opening a new tab or window, or even a different browser.

Comment: If students open a new tab, window or developer console they are redirected.

Comment: What is meant by "function name = undefined".  Is this an error you are seeing?  Where?

Answer (score 0):

locked isn't actually doing anything, because you set it to 1 and then check if it's equal to 1 straight away.

Then an event listener is created - when you change the value of locked, this event listener is still there. You need to remove it or check the value of locked in the event listener itself.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have an example of what this might look like?  The lockdown function works already but stoplockdown doesn't.

Comment: Try putting `if (locked==1) {...` inside the event listeners as well. 

Also note the other commenters is right, this might 'work' but someone clever can easily get around it by interfering with the JavaScript in their browser.